# How can I use a fake backend that is localhost on development when on production environment

Tags: reactjs, rest

I am following this tutorial https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/09/16/react-redux-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example#user-service-js

It creates a fake backend using localhost, and then it mocks a data base on localstorage

I would like to deploy my app on heroku or something similar

Is it possible?

Here is the service code, where config is "http://localhost:4000".

Thanks in advance

```
import config from 'config';
import { authHeader } from '../_helpers';

export const userService = {
    login,
    logout,
    register,
    getAll,
    getById,
    update,
    delete: _delete
};

function login(username, password) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
    };

    return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/users/authenticate`, requestOptions)
        .then(handleResponse)
        .then(user => {
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));

            return user;
        });
}

function logout() {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
}

function getAll() {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: authHeader()
    };

    return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/users`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}

function getById(id) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: authHeader()
    };

    return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/users/${id}`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}

function register(user) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    };

    return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/users/register`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}

function update(user) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: { ...authHeader(), 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    };

    return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/users/${user.id}`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);;
}

// prefixed function name with underscore because delete is a reserved word in javascript
function _delete(id) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: authHeader()
    };

    return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/users/${id}`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}

function handleResponse(response) {
    return response.text().then(text => {
        const data = text && JSON.parse(text);
        if (!response.ok) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                logout();
                location.reload(true);
            }

            const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText;
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        return data;
    });
}
```

Fake back end

```
// array in local storage for registered users
let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || [];

export function configureFakeBackend() {
    let realFetch = window.fetch;
    window.fetch = function (url, opts) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // wrap in timeout to simulate server api call
            setTimeout(() => {

                // authenticate
                if (url.endsWith('/users/authenticate') && opts.method === 'POST') {
                    // get parameters from post request
                    let params = JSON.parse(opts.body);

                    // find if any user matches login credentials
                    let filteredUsers = users.filter(user => {
                        return user.username === params.username && user.password === params.password;
                    });

                    if (filteredUsers.length) {
                        // if login details are valid return user details and fake jwt token
                        let user = filteredUsers[0];
                        let responseJson = {
                            id: user.id,
                            username: user.username,
                            firstName: user.firstName,
                            lastName: user.lastName,
                            token: 'fake-jwt-token'
                        };
                        resolve({ ok: true, text: () => Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(responseJson)) });
                    } else {
                        // else return error
                        reject('Username or password is incorrect');
                    }

                    return;
                }

                // get users
                if (url.endsWith('/users') && opts.method === 'GET') {
                    // check for fake auth token in header and return users if valid, this security is implemented server side in a real application
                    if (opts.headers && opts.headers.Authorization === 'Bearer fake-jwt-token') {
                        resolve({ ok: true, text: () => Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(users))});
                    } else {
                        // return 401 not authorised if token is null or invalid
                        reject('Unauthorised');
                    }

                    return;
                }

                // get user by id
                if (url.match(/\/users\/\d+$/) && opts.method === 'GET') {
                    // check for fake auth token in header and return user if valid, this security is implemented server side in a real application
                    if (opts.headers && opts.headers.Authorization === 'Bearer fake-jwt-token') {
                        // find user by id in users array
                        let urlParts = url.split('/');
                        let id = parseInt(urlParts[urlParts.length - 1]);
                        let matchedUsers = users.filter(user => { return user.id === id; });
                        let user = matchedUsers.length ? matchedUsers[0] : null;

                        // respond 200 OK with user
                        resolve({ ok: true, text: () => JSON.stringify(user)});
                    } else {
                        // return 401 not authorised if token is null or invalid
                        reject('Unauthorised');
                    }

                    return;
                }

                // register user
                if (url.endsWith('/users/register') && opts.method === 'POST') {
                    // get new user object from post body
                    let newUser = JSON.parse(opts.body);

                    // validation
                    let duplicateUser = users.filter(user => { return user.username === newUser.username; }).length;
                    if (duplicateUser) {
                        reject('Username "' + newUser.username + '" is already taken');
                        return;
                    }

                    // save new user
                    newUser.id = users.length ? Math.max(...users.map(user => user.id)) + 1 : 1;
                    users.push(newUser);
                    localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));

                    // respond 200 OK
                    resolve({ ok: true, text: () => Promise.resolve() });

                    return;
                }

                // delete user
                if (url.match(/\/users\/\d+$/) && opts.method === 'DELETE') {
                    // check for fake auth token in header and return user if valid, this security is implemented server side in a real application
                    if (opts.headers && opts.headers.Authorization === 'Bearer fake-jwt-token') {
                        // find user by id in users array
                        let urlParts = url.split('/');
                        let id = parseInt(urlParts[urlParts.length - 1]);
                        for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                            let user = users[i];
                            if (user.id === id) {
                                // delete user
                                users.splice(i, 1);
                                localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        // respond 200 OK
                        resolve({ ok: true, text: () => Promise.resolve() });
                    } else {
                        // return 401 not authorised if token is null or invalid
                        reject('Unauthorised');
                    }

                    return;
                }

                // pass through any requests not handled above
                realFetch(url, opts).then(response => resolve(response));

            }, 500);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: is there code for the fake backend. If its on local host it would have to be in the root file system

Comment: @BradBall yes there is , it is here https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/09/16/react-redux-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example#fake-backend-js I will add it to the question

Comment: I'm unable to see it because the server is block in Russia (where I'm at) but you would have to host that server(heroku) and then change your api calls on the front end to the hosted URL

Comment: @BradBall thank you, i pasted the code in the response, anyways, what you say is quite simple, I will try it and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: all you have to do is look up how to deploy a simple server on heroku on youtube, also front end on netlify